# Tail on scala iterator

Tags: scala

I want to check that every line in a file, apart from the first header line, contains the string "14022015". I wanted to do this the Scala way and I came up with something clever (I thought) using`foldLeft`:

```
assert(Source.fromFile(new File(s"$outputDir${File.separator}priv.txt"))
  .getLines().foldLeft(true)((bool, line) => (bool && line.contains("14022015"))))
```

Until I found out about the header line, which needs to be excluded from the test. tail will not work as getLines returns an `Iterator` and not a `List`. Is there something else I can do (Scala wise)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`iterator.drop(1)` will help you achieve exactly what you need

UPD: A side note, consider using a recursive solution instead of `fold` in this case - `fold` will always scan the entire iterator, and based on your code it looks like you may want it to short-circuit, just like standard `a && b && c` is not going to evaluate expressions down the list as soon as it encounters a `false`

Answer (score 6):

Simply:

```
val res: Boolean = myFile.getLines.drop(1).forall(_.contains("14022015"))
```